# How to change the default path of Realm database in a React-Native Project?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am currently learning to develop a mobile application using React-Native. As I tried to integrate Realm Database into it, I would like to check if I really stored the values I inputted using Realm Studio.

However, the default path is /data/data/com.projectbucket/files/default.realm and I can't seem to find the path anywhere in the RN project directory. I thought changing the path would somehow bring me closer to what I want to check, but there seem to be no resources stating how to change the default path.

RN Version: 0.61.5
Realm Version: 3.5.0
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: have you found an solution for the same ? got same issue with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @jaythanki no I have not. What I did however was open the project using android studio and look into the project files where .realm file is located. I made a copy into desktop and opened it using Realm Studio. You can basically look into the stored data, but it is not real time. You have to re-do the method in order to check again if DB has been updated...